# How to insert the Linux command df -ht ext4 output into a database table

Tags: linux, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, archlinux

Can anyone help show me how to insert the Linux command data into the table

Example:

```
postgres@PTFPG01:/root$ df -ht ext4
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        98G   15G   79G  16% /
/dev/sdb1       2.0T  921G 1008G  48% /data
```

I have tried the pipe with insert and it's giving me an error:

```
root@PTFPG01:~# df -ht ext4 | psql -d DBA_Monitoring -p 6432 -U postgres -W Olxoo30 -c " insert into driver_size values()"
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "Olxoo30" ignored
Password:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1:  insert into driver_size values() 

create table driver_size (
Filesystem varchar (50),  
Size varchar (10), 
Used varchar (10),
Avail varchar (10),
Use varchar (10),
Mounted_on  varchar (100)
);
```

Can anyone help show me how I can  insert the data into the table?

Comment: Ae you really using 9.1?  That is pretty ancient

Answer (score 2):

Does this work for you?

```
df -ht ext4 | tail -n+2 | sed -E "s/ +/\t/g"  | psql -d DBA_Monitoring -p 6432 -U postgres -W Olxoo30 -c 'copy driver_size from stdin;'
```

Answer (score 1):

The -W switch does not take your password as an argument; what it does is cause the program to prompt you for a password from the keyboard bypassing other mechanisms of getting one.  You should instead arrange to supply the password by one of those other mechanisms (PGPASSWORD, .pgpass, etc.), rather than bypassing them.

PostgreSQL doesn't have a COPY mode which supports one or more whitespace as a single separator, so you will need some other program to massage the output.  I picked `sed` to do that.  It may have a problem if any of your fields have literal whitespace in them.

Since COPY's text format does not support the HEADER option, I instead use `tail` to remove the header line.  Put them together and:

```
df -ht ext4 | sed 's/\s\s*/\t/g' | tail +2 | psql -c 'copy driver_size from stdin'
```